# Javascript wrapper that gives us Rubyish Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby

Are there any frameworks/wrapper out there that gives us rubyish javascript?

Instead of the usual for() {} loop gives us the object.each {} loop like in Ruby?

Since javascript could be used in web browsers I do want to use it for the server side too, but I do like ruby syntax far more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) library, having been developed by guys very close to Ruby on Rails, has a very Ruby-ish feel. It uses Ruby lingo (like mixins); for instance, the [`Enumerable` mixin](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/enumerable/) (which Prototype mixes in to arrays by default) adds the `each` method to an array, so you can do this:

```
["sample", "array"].each(function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

look up jQuery. it has a

```
$('.css-selector').each(function(i){
 //do stuff
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 2):

You might want to checkout [JS.Class - Ruby-style JavaScript](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/). From the docs,

> `JS.Class` is a set of tools designed to make it easy to build robust object-oriented programs in JavaScript. It’s based on Ruby, and gives you access to Ruby’s object, [module](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/modules.html) and [class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/classes.html) systems, some of its [reflection](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/reflection.html) and [metaprogramming](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/hooks.html) facilities, and a few of the packages from its standard library. It also provides a powerful [package manager](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/packages.html) to help load your applications as efficiently as possible.

It comes with a well packaged standard library including modules and classes such as

- Enumerable
- Hash
- Set
- Observable
- Command

The Enumerable module, for instance, is comparable to that [in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html), and includes methods like

```
all
any
collect
drop
findAll
forEach
grep
partition
reject
select
zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post by [Ken Egozi](http://www.kenegozi.com/blog/2009/04/13/javascript-and-the-extended-array-prototype.aspx) which discusses adding .forEach and other helpers to the array prototype.